# MyBatis/Ibatis :- Help regarding query in Ibatis/Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis, ibatis

I have written a query :-

```
 <select id="fetchEndPointArn" parameterType="map"   resultType="com.rohit.service.model.UserActive">
     select userid,endpointarns from t_user_actives where sid=#{sid}  
     and (userid in
     <foreach item="userid" index="index" collection="userid" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{userid}
     </foreach>
          )
 </select>
```

My DaoImpl:-

```
@Override
public List<UserActive> fetchEndPointArn(Map<String,String> map) {
    List<UserActive> userActive=sqlSession.selectList("fetchEndPointArn",map);
    return userActive;
}
```

map which I am passing contains  :-

```
sid=10,userid=t10,t12
```

I am getting an Exception saying :-

```
Error evaluating expression 'userid'.  Return value (t10,t12) was not iterable
```

Comment: Try to use different parameter name for `item` and `collection`.

Answer (score 1):

change the parameter type to `java.util.Map`. Define your collection as `collection="list" instead of collection="userid"`. Finally make userid an arraylist something like this

```
List userid = new ArrayList();
userid.add("t10");
userid.add("t12");
Map paramMap = new HashMap();
paramMap.put("sid",10);
paramMap.put("userid",userid);
```

And then in your xml

```
 <select id="fetchEndPointArn" parameterType="java.util.Map"   resultType="com.rohit.service.model.UserActive">
     select userid,endpointarns from t_user_actives where sid=#{sid}  
     and userid in
     <foreach item="userid" collection="list" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{userid}
     </foreach>
 </select>
```